# Custom action filter attribute throws null reference exception on invoking Antiforgery.Validate

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We are using angularjs ($http.post) to invoke controller. In controller we have defined a custom action filer attribute for validating the antiforgery token. The AntiForgery.Validate is throwing a null reference exception at: at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext().

we are using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc - 6.0.0-beta4

The custom attribute code is as follows.

```
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext actionContext)
  {
    if (actionContext == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("actionContext");
    }

    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

    var cookieToken = string.Empty;
    var formToken = string.Empty;
    string[] tokenHeaders = null;
    string[] tokens = null;

    if (actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("__RequestVerificationToken", out tokenHeaders))
            {
                tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
                if (tokens != null && tokens.Length == 2)
                {
                        cookieToken = tokens[0];
                        formToken = tokens[1];
                }
        }

        AntiForgery.Validate(actionContext.HttpContext, new AntiForgeryTokenSet(formToken, cookieToken));
}
```

Comment: Can you share how your request looks like?

Comment: Kiran you have answered it in the github MVC thread its the same question. Issue is resolved now... Thanks for the resolution... https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2579